# New Google App Engine Console - Front End Instance Not There

Tags: google-app-engine

I've noticed in the **NEW** AppEngine admin console(Google Developers Console), I can only set a daily budget

However if I'm in the *old* admin console(AppEngine Admin Console), I'm able to change the front end instance tiers (F1,F2,etc)

Did Google do away with instance tiers in the new version in favor of a daily budget? It's not exactly clear to users.

Comment: You can do this via app.yaml now, and if you have more than one module and want to change either the instance-class or scaling-mechanism must do it via the module's yaml file. I guess they decided having it in two places was confusing.

Comment: @Greg make this answer and I'll accept